# Avoid newpage when using abstract with article class

Tags: abstract

How is it possible to avoid LaTeX putting an abstract on a new page when using article class and titlepage enabled?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\begin{document}
Some text...
\begin{abstract} Some text unfortunately put on a new page \end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long you are not using `twocolumn` option, this will work.

I patched out the occurence of `\newpage` in the `titlepage` environment, which is used due to the `titlepage` option.

Since the original code contains `@` characters, `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` have to be used to give `@` a different meaning temporarily.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\titlepage}{\@restonecolfalse\newpage}{\@restonecolfalse}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\endtitlepage}{\if@restonecol\twocolumn \else \newpage \fi}{\if@restonecol\twocolumn \else  \fi}{\typeout{success}}{\typeout{fail}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Some text...

\begin{abstract} \blindtext \end{abstract}

Regular text:

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know at all what I'm doing there but it works perfectly so thank you very much ^_^

Comment: @OliverBorchert: An alternative would be to copy the abstract/titlepage code from `article.cls` and redefine it. So this is basically one 'smarter' approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just avoid using the abstract class altogether:

```
\begin{document}

\subsection*{Abstract}
Abstract text here

\section{First regular section}
Lorem ipsum

\end{document}
```